# How to remove array from Json object React Native

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

**i want a output of my array :**

```json
[
  {
    "discount": "0",
    "id": "2",
    "image": "https://punjabfoodhub.in/app/food_image/Dominos-Veg-Pizza-Margherita.jpg",
    "main_prise": "140",
    "name": "Margherita (Medium) 8\""
  },
  {
    "discount": "0",
    "id": "3",
    "image": "https://punjabfoodhub.in/app/food_image/Dominos-Veg-Pizza-Margherita.jpg",
    "main_prise": "170",
    "name": "Margherita (Large) 10\""
  }
]
```

**But my output is :**

```json
[
  {
    "discount": "0",
    "id": "2",
    "image": "https://punjabfoodhub.in/app/food_image/Dominos-Veg-Pizza-Margherita.jpg",
    "main_prise": "140",
    "name": "Margherita (Medium) 8\""
  },
  [
    {
      "discount": "0",
      "id": "3",
      "image": "https://punjabfoodhub.in/app/food_image/Dominos-Veg-Pizza-Margherita.jpg",
      "main_prise": "170",
      "name": "Margherita (Large) 10\""
    }
  ]
]
```

So how can I achieve my required output?

**my code is**

```js
fetch('https://punjabfoodhub.in/app/reg.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    item_id: ids,
    func: 'item_data',
  }),
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => {
    if (this.state.item_data.length == 1) {
      var temp = [];
      temp = this.state.item_data;
      temp.push(json);
      this.setState({ item_data: temp });

      console.log(this.state.item_data);
    } else {
      this.setState({ item_data: json });
    }
    //this.state.item_data.push(json);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: What methods have you tried upto now?

Comment: The response form the server is probably an array. `this.setState(state => ({ item_data: state.item_data.concat(json) }) )`